# Distinct class for small tasks or a general class containing small tasks?

Tags: design-patterns

Considering performance and speed, What type of programming do you prefer ?
A single class that doing small task or a general class that containing those small tasks ?

Example for General class:

general.class.php file :

```
class General{

    public function loadCache(){}
    public function storeCache(){}

    public function setSession(){}
    public function getSession(){}
}
```

Example for distinct class :

session.class.php file :

```
<?php
class Session{
    public function get(){};
    public function set(){};
}
?>
```

cache.class.php file :

```
<?php
    class Cache{
        public function loadCache(){}
        public function storeCache(){}
    }
?>
```

Comment: [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) favors the 2nd example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good object oriented design intends to have the code easy to maintain and understood. SRP , single responsibility principle tells us to group togather only a logical sets of APIs in a class such that these APIs aim to serve a single well defined task. While SRP helps and is good principle to follow but if not well implemented can lead to lots of Lilliput classes. Its your application, you are the best judge to see if your class serves a well defined purpose (the class name may help). Decompose your class if it does more than what its name sugguests.

See if the names of the classes are too general (pay special attention to classes having in their names words like : manager, controller, initilizer) or consists of separators like 'and'. These are few ways to let you know your swiss knife classes. Decompose your such classes into smaller classes, (once decomposed you may see few classes with similar APIs but different implementations. You may need to define common Interface for them). You may also need to use composition to have the functioanlity implemented.

Also make sure you do not decompose to a level which produces many lilliput classes.